# AWS S3 and Databricks advice on set up

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, databricks

I am looking for some advice on how we should process and hold our data on AWS s3 and load data within Databricks:

We are dropped hourly CSV files to AWS s3 which are zipped (gzip) format.

```
“s3://Files/2018/12/18/hourly_data_2018121800.gz”
```

So by the end of the day we have 24 files per day.

So each morning around 3am to allow for time delays, I load in yesterdays files.

```
load_name = '/mnt/Files/' + yr + '/' + mth + '/' + dy

s3_files = spark.read.format("csv")\
                     .options(header='True', inferSchema='True')\
                     .load(load_name)
```

I then perform a few data wrangling tasks (renaming columns and changing data types)

Nothing too intensive.

I then write in to another directory in s3:

```
file_name = 's3n://AWS_KEY:AWS_SECRET_KEY@new-file-directory/year=' + yr + '/month=' + mth + '/day=' + dy' + '/'

s3_files.write.format("parquet")
              .mode('overwrite')
              .save(file_name)
```

I have written to Parquet format so I can use AWS Athena to quickly query the data, and our data can then be pulled through to our BI tool Tableau.

But we also have tasks which we want to use Databricks for analysis, much more detailed deep dive in to it.

Example:

I will load in all of 2018 data:

```
load_name = '/mnt/new-file-directory/year=2018/month=**/day=**/'

s3_files = spark.read.format("parquet")\
                     .options(header='True', inferSchema='True')\
                     .load(load_name)
```

This is where we would start to build out our analysis and get in to the data.
The performance of loading many days is not as good as we would like it to be.

At the moment these are the tools open to us, but we are open to changing them.

Comment: How many files are there per partition and what size are they?

Comment: @JSmith I would say they range from 7 to 9 files per partition. The average size per partition is 30mb.